# AngularJS + Adobe CQ5 - Browser URL does not append hash path but changes the view

Tags: angularjs, aem

I am using combination of AngularJS and Adobe CQ5.

I have implemented routing to load different views. The views are loading perfectly but the URL is not appending the `#/path` and it shows the base path only, e.g.

- **localhost:7001/cf#/content/requestpage.html#/**

rather than

- **localhost:7001/cf#/content/requestpage.html#/checkstatus**.

Due to this, when I refresh the page it loads the route path (/) template instead of loading the same view again.

I am struggling to resolve this issue. Here's my controller code:

```
var demoapp=angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute','ngSanitize']);
demoapp.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

    // use the HTML5 History API
        //$locationProvider.html5mode(false);
    $routeProvider


              .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/content/index.html?wcmmode=disabled',
                controller: 'myfirstcontroller'
            })
                    .when('/checkstatus', {
                templateUrl: '/content/housetemplate.html?wcmmode=disabled',
                controller: 'houseController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
              });
        });

demoapp.controller('houseController', function($scope, $routeParams,$http)
{
//code
});

demoapp.controller('myfirstcontroller', function($scope,$http,$rootScope,$location,$compile)
{ 


    //On Form Submit
    $scope.continueForm = function(isValid){

        if (isValid) 
        {
              $location.path('/checkstatus');


        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with CQ5. When you open a page from Siteadmin, by default your page is loaded within **contentfinder** (`/cf#`).

Now, contentfinder already has your page URL as the hashvalue. Hence you find that the URL doesn't get updated even though your angular views work correctly.

Try accessing the same page without contentfinder. i.e.,

`http://localhost:7001/content/requestpage.html`

instead of

```
http://localhost:7001/cf#/content/requestpage.html
```

You should find things working as expected.

Comment: Yes this solution worked for Google Chrome and firefox.
But if i remove /cf# from the url in IE the page does not load the whole page. With /cf# in the url IE loads the initial page properly. I have IE 9 on my machine. What is the Issue with IE? I Have CQ components on my page.

Comment: It could be anything. I cannot directly tell what is the issue with IE without a bit more info. Check if there is any script errors that are shown in the developer console and post the details.